# Como extrair dígitos de uma string em Python e somá-los entre si?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algoritmo

Preciso decompor uma *string* em Python, separando letra e números, e realizar a soma desses números. Por exemplo:

**string** = "96h11k"

Dessa *string* preciso extrair os números 9, 6, 1, 1 e somá-los: 9 + 6 + 1 + 1 = 17. Na realidade, a soma acontece entre os dígitos.

Comment: Isso te ajuda? [`str.isdigit()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) Ou você quer um exemplo mais completo? Já tem algum código iniciado que está te trazendo dificuldades? (em outras palavras, diga-nos o que você já sabe e o que ainda falta saber. A propósito, isso é algum exercício, ou é pra usar na prática? Eu posso te dar um *one-liner* que faz isso, ou posso explicar mais detalhadamente, com loops, etc.)

Comment: É apenas um exercício. Preciso melhorar manipulação de string. Consigo manipular números, mas não consigo muito manipular strings, aí vi esse problema e estou tentando resolver...

Comment: Por exemplo... a função str.isdigit() retorna True ou False... no caso eu teria que dividir a string e verificar cada digito?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Você pode fazer isso com loops ou - se já conhecer o conceito - compreensões de lista. Estou escrevendo uma resposta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em Python, você pode iterar sobre uma *string* como se fosse uma lista:

```
>>> for ch in string:
...   print(ch)
...
9
6
h
1
1
k
```

No *loop* acima, a cada iteração `ch` será uma *string* de 1 caractere. Para saber se esse caractere é numérico ou não, você pode usar [`ch.isdigit()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm). Para convertê-lo para um inteiro, você pode usar [`int(ch)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). Então é só somar tudo:

```
soma = 0
for ch in string:
    if ch.isdigit():
        soma += int(ch)
print(soma)
```

Uma maneira mais concisa de se fazer isso é utilizando compreensões de lista (ou expressões geradoras), e a função [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) (somatório). Para um exemplo, ver [a resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42281/215).

Comment: muito obrigada! Deu certo! Ainda não posso votar na sua resposta, não tenho 15 pontos de reputação... :-/

Answer (score 12):

Segundo [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550071/221800) poderia usar funções prontas para isto:

```
def sum_digits(digit):
    return sum(int(x) for x in digit if x.isdigit())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/l1bIXB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/irbctawl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/SumDigits.py).

Desta forma está usando a função `sum()` cujos dados são gerados através de uma compreensão de lista onde cada elemento da lista (uma *string* é uma lista de caracteres) é decomposto individualmente.

Neste caso está pegando o parâmetro `digit` e analisando cada um de seus elementos, ou seja, cada um dos caracteres. Se o elemento pego for considerado um dígito numérico (função `isdigit()`) ele será entregue para o algoritmo da função `sum()` que sabe como somá-los.

Também dá para fazer manualmente conforme mostrado pela [resposta do mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42282/101).

Answer (score 3):

```
my_string = "96h11k"
soma = sum([int(i) for i in my_string if i.isdigit()])
```

--------EDIT---------

Agora que vi que minha resposta está idêntica à do `Maniero`...

Para a resposta não ficar completamente inútil, vai ai uma leitura sobre [*generator expressions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: Obrigada por sua colaboração!

Answer (score 1):

```
fim=int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))
string = str(fim)
soma = 0
for ch in string:
    if ch.isdigit():
        soma += int(ch)
print(soma)
```