# É possível somar int com str composta de texto e números em Python?

Tags: python, string, int

Fiz essa pergunta [Por que no PHP a expressão "2 + '6 maçãs'" é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80767/por-que-no-php-a-express%C3%A3o-2-6-ma%C3%A7%C3%A3s-%C3%A9-igual-a-8) aqui por achar esse comportamento estranho.

E no caso do `python`?

Eu consigo converter a string `'1'` *str* para `1` *int*.

Exemplo:

```
1 + int('1') # Imprime: 2
```

Porém, se eu tentar converter `'1 cachorro'` *str* para *int* ...

```
int('1 cachorro');
```

... é gerado um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 cachorro'
```

Seria possível fazer com que expressões do tipo `1 + int('1 cachorro')` funcione em `python`?

Se eu precisasse fazer isso (creio que nunca vou precisar), como poderia tratar esse caso?

Comment: A dúvida do Wallace Maxter acabou sendo pra mim também, mas achei a solução aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42280/como-extrair-d%C3%ADgitos-de-uma-string-em-python-e-som%C3%A1-los-entre-si

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Seria possível fazer com que expressões do tipo `1 + int('1 cachorro')` funcione em python?

Não. [Ou você soma inteiros](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) [ou concatena *strings*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). Isso faz parte da segurança de tipos do Python.

> Se eu precisasse fazer isso (creio que nunca vou precisar), como poderia tratar esse caso?

A única operação razoável seria a concatenação de *strings*. Se você quiser somar um inteiro numa *string* em lugares em que o Python tenha localizado números - que seria essa a interpretação mais exótica da sua pergunta -, você teria que escrever sua própria função para realizar isso, e não seria usando o operador de soma.

Comment: _loucura_ do PHP vs _sanidade_ do Python! Qual escolher?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters E ainda pergunta.

Comment: No PHP você só não pode somar um `int` com `array`. Se não gera um Erro fatal (e muitos inocentes caem nessa, sem tratar os dados que vêm da url)!

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta já possui uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8075959/3293600) na versão em inglês do StackOverflow!

O operador '+' funciona assim:

- Se os 2 operandos forem números: efetua a soma
- Senão: concatena strings.

Se a string conter apenas números ele consegue converter para inteiro.. caso contrário dá uma exception.

Por isso, no código onde você deseja converter uma string pra int você deve "esperar" que uma exceção aconteça.

```
string = "abcd"
try:
    i = int(string)
    print i
except ValueError:
    #Trata a exceção
    print 'a string não é um número'
```

Comment: Desculpa, Pedro, mas ainda não sou muito bom no inglês.

Comment: vou colocar o que é importante na resposta

Comment: Agora, sim. Quando vi o Link, fiquei meio perdido em qual das respostas do SOEN você estava apontando. Dica: Sempre clique em "share" na resposta, pois o link gerado cairá direto na resposta da pergunta :)

Comment: valeu pela dica.. editei o link !

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o que queres, penso que pode fazer o seguinte:

```
int( re.search(r'\d+', '1cachorro).group() )
```

O que isto vai fazer é pegar na string que colocou, procurar o inteiro e retorna-lo. Depois pode usar esse valor para fazer a sua soma.